How do i add Skip in ShowcaseView
I added a ShowcaseView on my app, i want to make user to also skip, but looking at the documentation i cant find where to skip, but the ShowcaseView will force user to see all before stopping which is not good.
let assume i added 20 items as a ShowcaseView the user will have to see all before it will stop, which is not good for users
is there a way to add Skip on the overlay so that user can skip the ShowcaseView, or if there is other way or Library i can use

You can use the Showcase.withWidget constructor to add a skip button to the user and call the ShowCaseWidget.of(context).dismiss method to close the ShowcaseView. I found a code snipped from a discussion on this issue.
Showcase.withWidget(
   key: YOURWIDGETKEY,
   width: double.infinity, // need fix width, you can use the whole width like this
   height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2, // for displaying showcase upper or lower to the widget
   container: Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 24
      child: Column(
         children: [
            Text("Title", style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6),
            Text("Description"),
            Divider(),
            TextButton(
               style: TextButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.grey),
               child: Text("skip"),
               onPressed: ShowCaseWidget.of(context).dismiss, // dismisses the current showcase procedure
            ),
         ],
      ),
   ),
)

https://github.com/SimformSolutionsPvtLtd/flutter_showcaseview/issues/99

so after i add the Showcase.withWidget but  there no parameter to add the title and discription again

now i understand...
